# Firestore emulator fails to clean data in GitHub Actions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have a test that runs smoothly in my local machine, and it used to do it in GitHub actions in the past.

Now it fails when I call the API to delete existing data in the Firestore emulator after every test is run.

I got the following message

```
⚠  Authenticating with `FIREBASE_TOKEN` is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version of `firebase-tools`. Instead, use a service account key with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, pubsub, storage
i  emulators: Detected demo project ID "demo-test", emulated services will use a demo configuration and attempts to access non-emulated services for this project will fail.
⚠  functions: You are not signed in to the Firebase CLI. If you have authorized this machine using gcloud application-default credentials those may be discovered and used to access production services.
⚠  It appears you are running in a CI environment. You can avoid downloading the Firestore Emulator repeatedly by caching the /home/runner/.cache/firebase/emulators directory.
i  firestore: downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.16.2.jar...
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.
⚠  It appears you are running in a CI environment. You can avoid downloading the Pub/Sub Emulator repeatedly by caching the /home/runner/.cache/firebase/emulators directory.
i  pubsub: downloading pubsub-emulator-0.7.1.zip...
i  pubsub: Pub/Sub Emulator logging to pubsub-debug.log
⚠  It appears you are running in a CI environment. You can avoid downloading the Storage Emulator repeatedly by caching the /home/runner/.cache/firebase/emulators directory.
i  storage: downloading cloud-storage-rules-runtime-v1.1.3.jar...
i  functions: Watching "/home/runner/work/entropic-bond-firebase/entropic-bond-firebase/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: test, testCallablePersistent, testCallablePlain.
✔  functions[europe-west1-test]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/demo-test/europe-west1/test).
✔  functions[europe-west1-testCallablePersistent]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/demo-test/europe-west1/testCallablePersistent).
✔  functions[europe-west1-testCallablePlain]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/demo-test/europe-west1/testCallablePlain).
i  Running script: jest --forceExit
FAIL src/store/firebase-datasource.spec.ts (11.628 s)
  ● Firestore Model › should find document by id
    TypeError: fetch failed
      43 |  afterEach( async ()=>{
      44 |      await terminate( FirebaseHelper.instance.firestore() )
    > 45 |      await fetch( 'http://localhost:9080/emulator/v1/projects/demo-test/databases/(default)/documents', {
         |      ^
      46 |          method: 'DELETE'
      47 |      })
      48 |  })
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/firebase-datasource.spec.ts:45:3)
    Cause:
    connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:9080
```

I've tried fetching 127.0.0.1 instead `localhost` as suggested in other comments, but this I only get a timeout with useless feedback.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that Node v18.x favours ipv6 in front of ipv4

You can fix the problem by calling

```
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first')
```

at the beginning of your file

see https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1624#issuecomment-1407717012

Comment: Alternatively using an explicit IPv4 address can work also